# How to quit a bash script on error unless stdout has a certain message?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'd like to run two commands in bash, and afterwards if either of them failed, quit my script. I've got the following which does exactly that:

```sh
echo "Linking ${bold}Linux PTB${normal} ${PTB_VERSION}..."
dblsqd push -a mudlet -c public-test-build -r "${PTB_VERSION}" -s mudlet --type "standalone" --attach linux:x86_64 "${LINUX_PTB_URL}" || EXIT_CODE_LINUX=$?
echo "Linking ${bold}macOS PTB${normal} ${PTB_VERSION}..."
dblsqd push -a mudlet -c public-test-build -r "${PTB_VERSION}" -s mudlet --type "standalone" --attach mac:x86_64 "${MACOS_PTB_URL}" || EXIT_CODE_MACOS=$?

if [ "${EXIT_CODE_LINUX}" != 0 ] && [ "${EXIT_CODE_MACOS}" != 0 ]; then
  exit 1
fi
```

This works great. Now, I'd like my exit condition to take into account the output of stdout and stderr - if it contains `exists already for this release`, then do *not* consider the exit code in this case.

I've tried doing this:

```sh
EXIT_CODE_LINUX=0
LINUX_OUTPUT=$(mktemp)
EXIT_CODE_MACOS=0
MACOS_OUTPUT=$(mktemp)
echo "Linking ${bold}Linux PTB${normal} ${PTB_VERSION}..."
dblsqd push -a mudlet -c public-test-build -r "${PTB_VERSION}" -s mudlet --type "standalone" --attach linux:x86_64 "${LINUX_PTB_URL}" 1>$LINUX_OUTPUT || EXIT_CODE_LINUX=$?
echo "Linking ${bold}macOS PTB${normal} ${PTB_VERSION}..."
dblsqd push -a mudlet -c public-test-build -r "${PTB_VERSION}" -s mudlet --type "standalone" --attach mac:x86_64 "${MACOS_PTB_URL}" 1>$MACOS_OUTPUT || EXIT_CODE_MACOS=$?
[ -z "$EXIT_CODE_LINUX" ] || [ "$LINUX_OUTPUT" != *"This combination of os:arch and type exists already for this release."* ] && exit 1
[ -z "$EXIT_CODE_MACOS" ] || [ "$MACOS_OUTPUT" != *"This combination of os:arch and type exists already for this release."* ] && exit 1
```

But that just made it ignore all exit codes. What is the right approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in a subshell to get output and check it. Like this:

```
...
echo "Linking ${bold}Linux PTB${normal} ${PTB_VERSION}..."
data=$(dblsqd push -a mudlet -c public-test-build -r "${PTB_VERSION}" -s mudlet --type "standalone" --attach linux:x86_64 "${LINUX_PTB_URL}"); EXIT_CODE_LINUX=$?
echo "$data"
#check $data
re='exists already for this release'
[[ $data =~ $re ]] || no_exit=true
...
```

Add '2>&1' to the end of the command to also capture STDERR.